# Axis2 with OpenEJB error on Tomcat

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, service

I deployed on Tomcat Axis2 and OpenEjb and got the error.
If deploy either only axis2 or openejb, they works properly, but when deploy them together, Axis2 can't be deployed, but OpenEjb is available.
Could anybody help with this problem, please?

This is error that I got when Tomcat starts :

SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive axis2.war
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 48188
    at org.apache.xbean.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.openejb.util.AnnotationFinder.readClassDef(AnnotationFinder.java:251)
    at org.apache.openejb.util.AnnotationFinder.find(AnnotationFinder.java:157)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.discoverModuleType(DeploymentLoader.java:1198)
    at org.apache.openejb.tomcat.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.loadApplication(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:552)
    at org.apache.openejb.tomcat.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.start(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:242)
    at org.apache.openejb.tomcat.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:58)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4377)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:905)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:740)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:500)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, I needed Axis2 only for webservices, so as openejb supports webservices as well, I, finally, installed only openejb. As openejb includes the same features as axis2 (at least, for my needs) and even more, so the installation of both openejb and axis2 om Tomcat is unnecessary in my case.